# Infinite scroll Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll for my app built in flutter, but I have a problem.
I want load more elements when I reach the end of my list.

And I tried with this code (I will put a pastebin for more comfort https://pastebin.com/StwTpj0M):

```
 void initState() {
    loadItems();
    _scrollController..addListener(_onScroll);
    super.initState();
  }
 final _scrollThreshold = 200.0;
 void _onScroll() {
    final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;

    if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
      //this is called many time
      print("limit reached");
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder
                  (
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemCount: litems.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                      return new Text(litems[index]);
                    }
                ),
              )

            ],
          ),
        );
```

But the problem is that in the function **_onScroll** that I've created, the block:

```
if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
      print("limit reached");
    }
```

Is called many time, and indeed it will print many times my string.
Obviously this is a problem because if I put an async call to my backend, it fires many times same call.

I've followed this tutorial, in my real application I use Bloc but the problem is the same.

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial

Answer (score 0):

Do google codelabs, they show the working with proper instructions.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#0